# How can you return the length of the number of distinct keys in a list of dictionaries without including keys that have already been seen?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
self.dl = ({'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'c':13, 'd':14, 'e':15}, {'e':25, 'f':26, 'g':27})
```

I have this tuple of dictionaries and am trying to get the count of all the distinct keys. I am only able to do this so that all the keys are counted. The output here should be 7 but I am getting 9 because c and e are being counted twice.

I have this so far:

```
new = []
for d in self.dl:
    for k in d:
        new.append(k)
return len(new)
```

Comment: Use a `set()`, e.g `return len(set(k for d in self.dl for k in d))`

Comment: That's a tuple, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import or_ as union
from functools import reduce

len(reduce(union, map(dict.keys, self.dl)))
```

The view returned by `keys()` already acts like a set. So if you take the union (`or_`) of all the key sets from your dicts, you get the set of all keys. The length of that set is the number of unique keys.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tested the code and got a `7`. Why wouldn't `len` work on a set?

Comment: My mistake. I had the output in my head as a generator, bit not a set. Time to sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try something like this:

```
new = {}
for d in self.dl:
    for k in d:
        if k not in new:
            new[k] = 1
return len(new)
```

Comment: 2 things, you don't need the `if` condition keys are unique in a `dict`. Second, you don't need a `dict`, `new = set()` and `new.add(k)` would do the same thing.

Comment: @AChampion totally set() would do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)s are definitely the data structure you want here. There are a few different ways you can accumulate the set:

```
new = set(k for d in self.dl for k in d)
```

or

```
from itertools import chain
new = set(chain(*self.dl))
```

or

```
new = set()
for d in self.dl:
    new &= d.keys()
```

In all cases, `len(new)` will be the number of unique keys.